# Integrating tor in iOs app

Tags: ios, tor

How do I integrated tor into an iOs app so the user can select to access a site in a UIWebView either with or without using the tor network. Is there an approved library that can be used or would I need to write tor connection code from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Onion Browser](https://github.com/OnionBrowser/iOS-OnionBrowser)'s code - that should give you some pointers about how to get started.